# What are the mobile devices/ tablets supported by Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

We have an application with Sitecore backend. We wanted to know the list of Android/iOS/Windows Phone devices supported by Sitecore[i.,e to use the sitecore application itself on Mobile.] Please help us to identify the list of mobile devices/tablets supported by Sitecore.

Comment: Bit of a broad question. It all depends on how many your Sitecore partner implements your site in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We wanted to analyze and identify the list of mobile devices/versions supported by Sitecore.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the CMS backend site, you can take a look at this kb article to see the browser compatability list: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

The Sitecore CMS is a browser based admin interface. It does not have native applications to support content editing.  It is best done on a desktop - Mac or Windows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. This link was very useful to know the list of Desktop browsers supported by sitecore. We wanted to know the mobile/tablet browsers supported by Sitecore.

Comment: We are not looking to build a native application. We wanted to use the sitecore CMS on mobile browsers as well as wanted to identify the list of mobile/tablet browsers supported by CMS in such a way that the Sitecore CMS can be user friendly.